# CodeIgniter URL Structure parameters

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter to develop a web app

but i am facing some issues in url structure.

I need to have a url structure like below

`http://example.com/controller/function/parameters`

it means i am having a url like below

`http://183.83.52.151/ftp/deploy/a72520c9987ca4b4255c10db9d76d3cb`

in that url the string `a72520c9987ca4b4255c10db9d76d3cb` is a parameter i want to get it in my php code but its taking this as a whole url and returning me 404page

how i can get this done ?

My htaccess looks like below

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|images|css|js|install|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [l,QSA]
```

My Code Looks like below

`class ftp extends CI_Controller{
          public function deploy(){
              var_dump($_REQUEST); exit;
          }
       }`

Comment: can you have controller named as ftp and method in this class named as deploy?

Comment: post your code and file structure.

Comment: @AvinashSinha 

Yes i have a ftp as method and deploy as function

Comment: can you please share complete controller here so i am able to help you efficiently and also make sure about url routing. :-)

Comment: @AvinashSinha i have updated my question.

Comment: public function deploy($id){ // use $id here} read [this](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#passing-uri-segments-to-your-methods)

Comment: @VarunSridharan which version of codeigniter you are using?

Comment: @AvinashSinha    I am using the latest version of codeigniter

Comment: @Bugfixer
Thanks but i have one issue.

I am using a custom controller extended `CI_Controller` to restrict access to the protected page (User Login System) but i need to allow some page to be accessed without login.

Comment: @AvinashSinha  Thanks but i have one issue. I am using a custom controller extended CI_Controller to restrict access to the protected page (User Login System) but i need to allow some page to be accessed without login.

Comment: @AvinashSinha

here is my custom controller code http://pastebin.com/JwDNV3Xc

Comment: use routes to allow and deny access

Comment: Please change controller name first later in capital and class name as well

Comment: @Bugfixer i dont know to use routes. is there any document ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this as it

```
class Ftp extends CI_Controller{
      public function deploy($id){
          var_dump($id); exit;
      }
   }
```

and name the file is Ftp.php

Comment: Thanks but i have one issue. I am using a custom controller extended CI_Controller to restrict access to the protected page (User Login System) but i need to allow some page to be accessed without login.
 here is my custom controller code pastebin.com/JwDNV3Xc

Comment: what the actual issue you faced to getting this functionalities

Comment: you can also do that things with other method no need to extend base classes

Comment: Can you please giude me on how to restrict certain page been viewd with out login and some pages are public.

Comment: ok please accept the answer if issue is fixed and post another question regarding new one issue. That would be good and clean

Comment: Thanks. if you dont mind can i contact you via email ? my id is varunsridharan23@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Use **URI class** of codeigniter:

```
$data = $this->uri->segment(n);  // in your case, it is $this->uri->segment(3);
echo $data;
```

See the link: [URI Class](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html)

Comment: That is the very old and outdated user guide link you will find both new and old versions of docs here now http://www.codeigniter/docs

Comment: ellislab does not deal with codeigniter any more but for some reason they still have user guide.

Comment: @wolfgang1983 then they should remove now all the links.

Comment: so that it should not misguide to users. :) @varun is answer helped you?

Comment: @PathikVejani
I already know this method. but i dont want to get like this.
i cant be sure how the url will be 

so i need to use the $_GET method but i am getting it as `ftp/deploy/ajdgbkdjbgfsdjbg`